# Shockwaves in a colllision of two cylinders

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, shock-waves

On [Motion Mountain](https://www.motionmountain.net/index.html)'s first volume (fall, flow and heat) by Christoph Schiller, page 128, the author asks the following puzzle:

> A surprising effect is used in home tools such as hammer drills. We remember that when
> a small ball elastically hits a large one at rest, both balls move after the hit, and the small
> one obviously moves faster than the large one. Despite this result, when a short cylinder
> hits a long one of the same diameter and material, but with a length that is some integer
> multiple of that of the short one, something strange happens. After the hit, the small
> cylinder remains almost at rest, whereas the large one moves, as shown in Figure 87.
> Even though the collision is elastic, conservation of energy seems not to hold in this
> case. (In fact this is the reason that demonstrations of elastic collisions in schools are
> always performed with spheres.) What happens to the energy?

He states that the cause to this phenomenon is as follows (page 493):

> When the short cylinder hits the long one, two compression waves start to run from the point of contact through the two cylinders. When each compression wave arrives at the end, it is reflected as an expansion wave. If the geometry is well chosen, the expansion wave coming back from the short cylinder can continue into the long one (which is still in his compression phase). For sufficiently long contact times, waves from the short cylinder can thus depose much of their energy into the long cylinder. Momentum is conserved, as is energy; the long cylinder is oscillating in length when it detaches, so that not all its energy is translational energy. This oscillation is then used to drive nails or drills into stone walls. In commercial hammer drills, length ratios of 1:10 are typically used.

As a reference for this, he mentions (page 532):

> This and many other physics surprises are described in the beautiful lecture script by
> Josef Zweck, Physik im Alltag, the notes of his lectures held in 1999/2000 at the Universität Regensburg.

I, however, couldn't find neither the lecture script, nor another source analysing the same problem.
Is someone familiar with this phenomenon, and can give me a reference to a source on it?

Thanks in advance!